# How are OLE DB connection strings mapped to DLLs?

Tags: .net, ado.net, oledb, connection-string, database-connection

How does the OleDbConnection constructor know what provider DLL (I assume it's a DLL) to call for a given provider name in the connection string? For example, in the following code...

```
string cnStr = "Provider=Sybase.ASEOLEDBProvider.2;Server Name=etc...";
OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(cnStr);
```

How does OleDbConnection know where to find `Provider=Sybase.ASEOLEDBProvider.2`?

I'm trying to debug a data access problem in my Winforms app and I think it may be related to a driver bug that's been fixed, so I may need to upgrade my DLL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mapping is done in the registry.  For SQLOLEDB, I have a assembly location of `%CommonProgramFiles%\System\Ole DB\sqloledb.dll` under the appropriate class id.